# PDF file difference in ligature copying?

Tags: pdftex, luatex, ligatures

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
iffy fig flat office baffle
\end{document}
```

With the above .tex file, using lualatex and pdflatex would generate different PDFs in the sense that text can be copied from the former ouput with ligature expanded to the original characters, and the latter with only the ligatured characters.

I am trying to understand why there is a difference at the PDF file level. Could anybody show me how to inspect the PDF files to know why there is such a difference? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is a bit viewer dependent. With Okular I get the same as the input when I copy/paste. But you shouldn't use legacy encodings (`OT1`) with LuaLaTeX

Comment: You can add `\usepackage{l3pdf}\ExplSyntaxOn \pdf_uncompress: \ExplSyntaxOff` and then inspect the pdf.

Comment: The purpose is to understand the PDF format. But how to fix the problem in latex code.

Comment: as already said in your other question: Don't use OT1 with luatex. That will fix the issue.